# Load url from CSV to scrape data

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I would load a list of urls from csv to scrape data with selenium. I used this code:

```
    with open('urls.csv', 'r') as file:    
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        driver.get(row)
```

urls.csv:

```
https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2010-2011/results/
https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2011-2012/results/
https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2012-2013/results/
```

`print(row)`

`['https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2010-2011/results/']`

But I got this error on `driver.get(row)`
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string`

Comment: Where is the url argument? Where did you use it? Your code still not complete.

Comment: https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2010-2011/results/

https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2011-2012/results/

https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2012-2013/results/

https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2013-2014/results/

https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2014-2015/results/

Comment: Please, edit your post to be more clear!

Comment: please post the contents in urls.csv it looks like the rows in the csv are not urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV file has **rows** and **columns** like a two-dimensional array.

In your code, you iterated over the rows with `for row in reader:`, but you forgot to specify the column of the row with the **[n] operator**, with n being a natural number. This means that you pass an array instead of a string to the driver (shown by the square brackets in your print output) and selenium throws an exception.

Your URLs are in the first column of the CSV file. To get the strings, you specify the row with `row[0]` like this:

```
with open('urls.csv', 'r') as file:    
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader:
    print(row[0])
    driver.get(row[0])
```

You could also use a .txt file for the urls and iterate over the rows, because you are only using the first column of the CSV file.